# How Mongo .Net Driver closes the connection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an application that makes 5 queries at the same time and I might need to exit the application before all of them are done, I would like to know how can I cancel all current operations that my MongoClient is making and close the connection.

From what I read at another question in stackoverflow, there's no need to close or dispose of connections in MongoClient because the client handles it automatically so the client will close the connection when the application exits but will the client wait for those queries to finish before closing automatically or will it immediately close? If it waits, how can I make it cancel those queries and close the connection immediately rather than waitting?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to enforce disposing of the mongoClient, try this:

```
ClusterRegistry.Instance.UnregisterAndDisposeCluster(client.Cluster)
```